# iterating over a dictionary of empty pandas dataframes to append them with data from existing dataframe based on list of column names

Tags: pandas, for-loop, dictionary, dataframe

I'm a biologist and very new to Python (I use v3.5) and pandas. I have a pandas dataframe (df), from which I need to make several dataframes (df1... dfn) that can be placed in a dictionary (dictA), which currently has the correct number (n) of empty dataframes. I also have a dictionary (dictB) of n (individual) lists of column names that were extracted from df. The keys in 2 dictionaries match. I'm trying to append the empty dfs within dictA with parts of df based on the column names within the lists in dictB.

```
import pandas as pd
listA=['A', 'B', 'C',...]
dictA={i:pd.DataFrame() for i in listA}
```

lets say I have something like this:

```
dictA={'A': df1, 'B': df2}
dictB={'A': ['A1', A2', 'A3'],
       'B': ['B1', B2']}
df=pd.DataFrame({'A1': [0,2,4,5],
                 'A2': [2,5,6,7],
                 'A3': [5,6,7,8],
                 'B1': [2,5,6,7],
                 'B2': [1,3,5,6]})
listA=['A', 'B']
```

what I'm trying to get is for df1 and df2 to get appended with portions of df like this, so that the output for df1 is like this:

```
  A1 A2 A3
0 0  2  5
1 2  4  6
2 4  6  7
3 5  7  8
```

df2 would have columns B1 and B2.

I tried the following loop and some alterations, but it doesn't yield populated dfs:

```
for key, values in dictA.items():
    values.append(df[dictB[key]])
```

Thanks and sorry if this was already addressed elsewhere but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

You could create the dataframes you want like this instead :

```
df = #Your original dataframe containing all the columns
df_A = df.iloc[:][[col for col in df if 'A' in col]]
df_B = df.iloc[:][[col for col in df if 'B' in col]]
```

Comment: Thank you. This will work for a manageable number of dfs. I gave 2 dfs as an example. I have many dfs that I'd like to keep in one place, like in a dictionary and later in a panel, so this will need looping to populate n empty dfs that I have in dictA. Or a loop to directly make a dictionary of populated dfs.

Comment: then yes you may loop